# Document-based app in one window

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, document-based

I need to develop a simple document-based application but using only one window, the documents should open in views separated by tabs.
How can I achieve it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116886/multiple-documents-in-a-single-window-in-cocoa/1116897 for answer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is you can achieve what you want with a *lot* of hackery to shoehorn the Cooca `NSDocument` architecture into a single-window style. But you really don't want to do that. It's much easier to write your own system for document handling from scratch. Start with the Non-document based application template and go from there. `NSDocument` expects to have its own window (and associated `NSWindowControllers`).